# Рекурсивно инвертировать односвязный список

Tags: рекурсия, c++, список

Есть односвязный список

```
struct ListNode
{
ListNode* next;
int value;
}
```

Необходимо написать код простой функции

```
void ReverseList(ListNode* head);
```

которая инвертирует заданный список, используя рекурсию.
Я нашел одну из реализаций, но не могу понять как после инвертирования вернуть указатель на новый head. В этой реализации head указывает на конец списка.

```
void ReverseList(ListNode* head)
    {
        if(head->next)
        {
            ListNode* n=head->next;
            ReverseList(n);
            n->next=head;
            head->next=0;
        }
    }
```

Как изменить алгоритм чтобы он возвращал правильный head?

Comment: Это учебное задание? Если нет, не используйте рекурсию, тут она не просто не нужна, но и опасна. Если да, делайте сами, или спросите у одноклассников.

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Да, это учебное задание, вопрос в том как это реализовать именно используя рекурсию.

Comment: Кроме самой функции никто это не сделает. Просто она же и должна возвращать результат (вместо void).

Comment: Ну всмысле чтобы после выполнения алгоритма аргумент head указывал на начало инвертированого списка

Comment: @German, ну сами подумайте. 

Что такое начало инвертированного списка?

Очевидно - это последний элемент исходного. Вот его-то и надо возвращать, раскручивая рекурсию.